# Custom regex to format number

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

i have this number
1234567890

this is how i want to display it

1234 567 890

im trying this

```
console.log('1234567899'.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, '$1 '));
```

Comment: which angular version are you using?

Comment: Can you explain the logic you're looking for? Do you want to omit the first comma when there is only one digit in the first section, or for two as well, or for all 3, or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to have an optional group that starts at the beginning of the string and (greedily) matches the number of the leading-digits-without-commas you want to have. Then, instead of replacing with just `\1`, replace with `\1\2` (the optional group *plus* the second captured digits):

```js
const format = str => str.replace(
  /(^(?:\d{1,2}))?(\d{1,3})(?=(?:\d{3})+$)/g,
  //       ^^^ change these to change the number of unbroken leading digits
  '$1$2 '
);

console.log(format('1234567899'));
console.log(format('01234567899'));
console.log(format('101234567899'));
```

The above snippet's optional group begins with `\d{1,2}`, which means that there will be between 3 and 5 leading digits, unbroken by commas. To change that quantity, just change the number of repetitions.

The leading group `(^(?:\d{1,2}))?` means: optionally, the beginning of the string, followed by one or two digits.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with this way.

```
let number = '1234567890';
let result = number.replace(/(\d{4})(\d{3})(\d{3})/, "$1 $2 $3");
console.warn(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

- Divide your string into 2 parts.

  - 1. String contains space after 4 digits
  - 2. String contains space after 3 digits.
- Add space after n digits

Try with this

```js
var str = "1234567890";
var temp = str.substring(0,4); // get first 4 digits
//Add space after 3 digits. You can use same logic to add space after 4 digits as well
var z = [...str.substring(4)].map((d, i) => i % 3 == 0 ? ' '+d : d).join('').trim();

//Concatenate both strings
var result = temp + ' ' + z;

//Display result 
console.log(temp);
console.log(z);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex which ensures the numbers will be grouped in bunches of three except the first digits which can be grouped from four to five.

Match `/(^\d{4}|\d{3})(?=(\d{3})*$)/g` and replace with `$1`

Here is some sample javascript code,

```js
console.log('1234567899' + ' --> ' + '1234567899'.replace(/(^\d{4}|\d{3})(?=(\d{3})*$)/g, '$1 '));
console.log('12345678991' + ' --> ' + '12345678991'.replace(/(^\d{4}|\d{3})(?=(\d{3})*$)/g, '$1 '));
console.log('123456789912' + ' --> ' + '123456789912'.replace(/(^\d{4}|\d{3})(?=(\d{3})*$)/g, '$1 '));
console.log('1234567899123' + ' --> ' + '1234567899123'.replace(/(^\d{4}|\d{3})(?=(\d{3})*$)/g, '$1 '));
```